# Spring post redirects to access-denied while get works

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, post

I apologize for a somewhat duplicate post, I asked a question about this yesterday however I did not do a good job of stating the problem and because of this the feedback was not useful. I have since learned more about the problem and can put it in a more clear and concise way which will hopefully help solve this.

Whenever I try to post to a page the controller maps the url to  the access-denied-handler as specified by mvc-dispatch-servlet.xml. If I try to get to a page then it hits the correct @requestmapping and everything is ok.

[image: Get and post to the same url getting different results]
I have tried adding

```
<intercept-url pattern="/pages/ReceiveFile" access="permitAll"/>
```

which does nothing.

I have just recently narrowed this problem down to

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

which seems to be blocking the post operations. If I change this to /pages/* then I can post to a page that is /ReceiveFile because it is mapped that way in web.xml. This skips the main controller altogether. With that setting if I try to go to pages/ReceiveFile it still goes through the controller and goes to the 403 page. I don't believe bypassing my controller with all post operations is a good permanent solution.

How do I allow these post operations to go through?

Thanks!

**Main Controller.java**
some code cut to reduce unnecessary length

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
  String URLroot = "pages/";

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('_discover')")
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/discover/**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView discover(HttpServletRequest request) {
    StringBuffer mapping = request.getRequestURL();
    String URLoffset = getURLoffset(mapping);

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Login Form - Database Authentication");
    model.addObject("message", "This is default page no longer!");
    model.setViewName(URLoffset);
    return model;

  }

  /**
   * Upload single file using Spring Controller
   */
  @RequestMapping(value = "/ReceiveFile", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
  public ModelAndView test(){

    //Do useful things which require post.....


    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("springtest");
    return model;
  }


  @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView adminPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
    StringBuffer mapping = request.getRequestURL();
    String URLoffset = getURLoffset(mapping);

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Login Form - Database Authentication");
    model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
    model.setViewName(URLoffset);

    return model;

  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/signout", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
  public ModelAndView login() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("signout");
    return model;

  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
      model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
      model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    model.setViewName("login");
    return model;

  }

  //for 403 access denied page
  @RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
  public ModelAndView accesssDenied() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

    //check if user is logged in
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
//      UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
      System.out.println(auth.getName());
      model.addObject("username", auth.getName());

    }

    model.setViewName("/403");
    return model;

  }

  /**
   * Upload single file using Spring Controller
   */
  @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile2", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
  public @ResponseBody
  String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
          @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

      if (!file.isEmpty()) {
          try {
              byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

              // Creating the directory to store file
              String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
              File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
              if (!dir.exists())
                  dir.mkdirs();

              // Create the file on server
              File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                      + File.separator + name);
              BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                      new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
              stream.write(bytes);
              stream.close();

              instance.debug("FileUploadController" + " uploadFileHandler", "Server File Location=" + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());


              return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
          }
      } else {
          return "You failed to upload " + name
                  + " because the file was empty.";
      }
  }


}
```

**mvc-dispatch-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />
    <!-- Currently not working. Made a work around by having resources at /resources and pages at /pages -->
  <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/" />

    <!-- also add the following beans to get rid of some exceptions -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize"> 
            <value>100000</value>
        </property>        
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />
    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- login page must be available to all. The order matters, if this is after something which secures the page this will fail. -->
<!--        <intercept-url pattern="/SignupUserServlet" access="permitAll"/> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/ReceiveFile" access="permitAll"/> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/fileUpdate2" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/admin/**" access="hasRole('_admin')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/trade/**" access="hasRole('_trader')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/discover/**" access="hasRole('_users')" />       
        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/pages/403" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/pages/login" 
            default-target-url="/pages/common/redirectportal" 
            authentication-failure-url="/pages/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-url="/pages/logout" logout-success-url="/pages/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <!--<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query=
                    "select email,pwhash, enabled from users where email=?"
                authorities-by-username-query=
                    "select email, groupname from usergroups where email =?  " /> 
        </authentication-provider> -->
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


        <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

      <servlet>
    <servlet-name>InitServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.InitServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>configfile</param-name>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.admin.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.user.UserServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SignupUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.user.SignupUserServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>ReceiveFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.user.ReceiveFile</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>6</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/UserServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>SignupUserServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/SignupUserServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ReceiveFile</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/ReceiveFile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's this line of configuration that's causing the problem in the spring-security.xml:

```
<csrf/>
```

If you enable [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) in the security, your post requests need to be updated to include some extra information. It explains why GET works, but POST doesn't.

In your case, try removing it, and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Wow! That fixed it! I didn't know you needed a csrf token with all post requests. This has fixed the majority of the form posts. The only thing left now is that there is some oddity where it will not let me post a enctype="multipart/form-data" form.

Answer (score 0):

for declaring URLs which are "open" there is a typo in your XML, permitAll is given as

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access='permitAll()' />
```

notice the `()`

Comment: Most of the things I've seen say permitAll with no () however I tried it with the parenthesis and it doesn't make a difference.